# Memory corruption when working with external C# methods

Tags: c#, .net

While playing with the CH341 library, I discovered a problem in the form of PVOID.
When I try to use the method with PVOID it corrupts the memory.

For example, there is a method for obtaining a descriptor. I tried to connect it with C# in different ways, but at best it does not change the buffer at all, and at worst it even damages something that I did not give it a link to.

From the header file:

```
BOOL    WINAPI  CH341GetDeviceDescr(  // Read device descriptor
    ULONG           iIndex,  // Specify the serial number of the CH341 device
    PVOID           oBuffer,  // Points to a buffer large enough to hold the descriptor
    PULONG          ioLength );  // Points to the length unit, the length to be read when input is the length to be read, and the actual read length after return
```

My code:

```
[DllImport(dllName)]
private static unsafe extern bool CH341GetDeviceDescr(ulong index, void* buffer, ref ulong length);

public static unsafe string GetDeviceDescr(ulong index)
{
    ulong length = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];

    if (!CH341GetDeviceDescr(index, &buffer, ref length))
        throw new Exception("It is not possible to get the value.");

    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, (int)length);
}
```

An error occurred while trying to use the buffer:
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."
It also damages the length by setting its value to 1427249798

I also tried through Marshal and GCHandle, but the buffer either does not change

Comment: Is `ULONG` the Win32 `ULONG`? If so, the C# equivalent is `uint`, not `ulong`. You should also pin `buffer` to get its address with a `fixed` statement to ensure it doesn't get moved while the pointer is used.

Comment: You are using an unsafe method!!!  The error means that the unsafe code is trying to access a memory location outside the range of memory.  C# is managed and when calling a unsafe method a range of memory is assigned with an exception handler if the code access memory outside of the range.  How and Where is the memory being allocated for oBuffer?  It must be allocated from Unmanaged memory using Marshal Allocate method.

Comment: @jdweng No, not necessarily. You can pass a pointer to managed memory if you pin the array. You don't _have_ to use unmanaged memory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people in the comments.

```
uint length = maxBufferLength;
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
fixed (void* point = buffer)
{
    if (!CH341GetDeviceDescr(index, point, ref length))
        throw new Exception("It is not possible to get the value.");
}
```

Comment: It was the [DllImport] declaration that was wrong.  You'd also be wise to declare the second parameter as byte[].

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**